# Are objects in string constant pool eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, string

How many objects will be eligible for garbage collection after completion of  compute method?

I have searched this question and everywhere the answer is 1.

```
public void compute(Object p)

    {

     Object a = new Object();

     int x = 100;

     String str = "abc";

    }
```

But as far as I know, the string constant pool is a part of the heap now in Java 7 and eligible for garbage collection.

According to me, 2 objects are eligible for garbage collection i.e  `a` and `str`.

Comment: Part of your confusion is your misconception about _variables_ and _objects_: `a` and `str` are simply variables, which might only reference some object (or maybe not). The objects being referenced on the other hand, they might be eligible for GC.

Comment: @kayamen, so basically you mean that  str  will also be garbage collected ?  as suggested by link you shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter **where** objects get created.

The **only** thing that matters is: is the object **alive**?

In other words: when the last **reference** to an object goes out of use (or the holder of that reference isn't alive anymore) then the object is eligible for garbage collection.

An object created locally in a method can't be reached any more - it is no longer alive when the method returns. Things would be different for example if that method would add `a` to some (still live) "global" list for example.

Regarding `str`, there are multiple misconceptions:

- no String object is created: the string literal goes into the **constant** pool. It would be a different story if you had used `new String("abc")` for example. In your case: no object, thus no garbage collection for that string.
- `str` is holding a reference. There is no garbage collection for references, just for objects.

Comment: The little code snippet in this question shows 2 objects that could potentially be eligible for GC! The newly created one in the first line of the method. And the string `"abc"` in the third line. I think, we should explain, why the latter is not eligible for GC.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose done ;-)

Comment: Just to be nitpicking: The string literal `"abc"` _is_ an object. It simply does not reside on the heap! The expression `new String("abc")` in fact deals with _two_ objects. </nitpicking>

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose sure it resides on the heap, since Java 7.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, does this mean that GC does not happen in SCP area. ? if not then if i do str=null; what will happen to dangling object in SCP ?